# typedef'ed struct c, how to access instances of struct which is declared as a pointer in typedef?

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct, typedef

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 5

typedef struct Vector
{
    int items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    int size;
} *VectorP;

// I am not allowed to change this struct definition.

int main()
{   
    VectorP *p;

    p = (VectorP *) malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof(VectorP));

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    //The problem is that I can't access instance of the vector this way ->    

    p->size = 0;
}
```

Searching online I found out that it is something to do with `VectorP` already being a pointer, I cannot change this because my professor wants it that way. How do I solve this?

Comment: `VectorP` is just an alias for `struct Vector *`. So `VectorP *p` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct Vector`. Just use `VectorP` if you want a pointer to the struct.

Comment: First of all, hiding pointers behind a typedef is a horrible-horrible idea. If I were you, I'd just use `struct Vector` and `struct Vector *`. Also, `sizeof(VectorP)` should be `sizeof(struct Vector)` so that it allocates memory for the vectors, not only for the pointers (incorrectly). Or even better, use `sizeof *p` for safety (in case your type ever changes). Furthermore, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY He probably only wants to allocate one Vector, not an array of vectors

Comment: `my professor wants it that way`. Then go find another one (seriously).

Comment: typedeffing pointers considered harmful. Please find another "professor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
VectorP *p;
p = (VectorP *) malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof(VectorP));
```

You need to use this instead:

```
VectorP p;
p = (VectorP) malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof(struct Vector));
```

Or, if you are only interested in allocating 1 `Vector` object and not an array of multiple `Vector` objects:

```
VectorP p;
p = (VectorP) malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));
```

Comment: Personally I like `sizeof *p`

Comment: And: don't cast malloc() . It is useless and potentially harmful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
VectorP p;

p = ( VectorP ) malloc( sizeof( *p ) );

p->size = 0;
```

If you want to allocate an array of structures then the allocation will look like

```
VectorP p;

p = ( VectorP ) malloc( DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof( *p ) );

p->size = 0;
```

or

```
p = ( VectorP ) malloc( DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof( *p ) );

p[0].size = 0;
```

Or if you want indeed to allocate an array of pointers to the structure then the code will looki like

```
VectorP *p;

p = ( VectorP * ) malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof( VectorP ) );

if (p == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
    exit(1);
} 

for ( int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CAPACITY; i++ )
{
    p[i] = ( VectorP ) malloc( sizeof( *p[i] ) );
}

p[0]->size = 0;
```

Comment: @Matt McNabb it is a typo. Should be sizeof( *p )

Answer (score 0):

The allocation should be:

```
VectorP p;

p = malloc( sizeof *p );
```

This allocates enough space for one of the thing that `p` points to, regardless of whatever that is.

Then you can access the items via `p->size`, `p->items[0]`, `p->items[1]`, etc.

In C you should [not cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) , and by using this pattern you can avoid the error of naming the wrong data type in the `sizeof` expression.

Your struct already contains an array of `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` items, so I am guessing that you just want one of these.  If actually allocated `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` copies of your struct then you would have a total of 25 (non-contiguous) items.